# ListView sticky header not working even using renderSectionHeader property on Android

Tags: react-native

thank you for react-native such a great technology :) Anyway, I've been testing some component lately and found a bug on ListView component on Android when rendering a list with section headers. The supposedly header to be stickied at the top of the content then get push by the next one is not working. The iOS equivalent works just fine tho.

I'm using react-native `0.29.2` on windows 7 64bit with react-native-cli `1.0.0`. With `23.0.1` android SDK.

I also put a sample App [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/TqUHtQ)(view rnplay.org) that you can test. The version of that app is `0.24.1` tho but it seems still not working right.

According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html):

> renderSectionHeader function
>
> (sectionData, sectionID) => renderable
>
> If provided, a sticky header is rendered for this section. The sticky
>   behavior means that it will scroll with the content at the top of the
>   section until it reaches the top of the screen, at which point it will
>   stick to the top until it is pushed off the screen by the next section
>   header.

But it seems really not working for me. Here is some part of the code

```
class ListViewTest extends Component {

  renderListRowView(rowData) {
    const { state, label, alarm = false } = rowData;

    return (
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.rowText}>{label}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderSectionHeader(data, sectionId) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.subheader}>
        <Text style={styles.subheaderText}>{sectionId}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  getSource() {
    return [{
      name: 'Category 1',
      todos: [{
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'checked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Categor 2',
        todos: [{
        state: 'checked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'checked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'checked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Eat Food'
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Category 3',
      todos: [{
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Go with the flow'
      }, {
        state: 'checked',
        label: 'Go with the flow'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Go with the flow'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Go with the flow'
      }, {
        state: 'unchecked',
        label: 'Go with the flow'
      }]
    }];
  }

  renderListViewData() {
    var data = this.getSource();
    var sectionIds = [];

    data.map((list) => {
      sectionIds.push(list.name);
      data[list.name] = list.todos;
    });

    return {data, sectionIds};
  }

  render() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      sectionHeaderHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    var {data, sectionIds} = this.renderListViewData();

    let dataSource = ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(data, sectionIds);

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ListView
          ref="listview"
          dataSource={dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderListRowView}
          renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          scrollEnabled={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ListViewTest', () => ListViewTest);
```

I also put a sample App [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/TqUHtQ) that you can test. The version of that app is `0.24.1` tho but it seems still not working right.

Any help would be really appreciated. Looking forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using property: stickySectionHeadersEnable. It seems to have solved the issue on android devices as i myself ran into same issue while using SwipeListView using renderSectionHeader.

Answer (score 0):

you must complete the API cloneWithRowsAndSections with all 3 arguments,and it will work.

Comment: You should be presenting an example of the code in your answer

Comment: Anyway,on android platform,it will not work till now.And on iOS ,before react-native version 0.43,a sticky header is a default setting and you can not close it , when you version >=0.43, there is a new property: stickySectionHeadersEnabled,so that you can control the sticky header,but also can't be used on android platform.

Comment: I am using SwipeListView from 'react-native-swipe-list-view' and the component specified in renderSectionHeader was not getting sticky in android but was working fine in ios. As @bo.jing suggested, i used stickySectionHeadersEnabled and it works like a charm on android as well now. Cheers.